# E/EE bond redemption by non-owner

Tags: united-states, savings-bonds, maturity

I have a few mature bonds from childhood that have been sitting in a safe deposit box under my parents' control.  I'm now an adult and currently live on the opposite coast.

Obviously I could have the bonds sent to me and cash them in in-person, but since I only have a Schwab account (no local bank), I would then need to turn that cash into a form that I could deposit electronically.  Logistically it seems it would be easier to authorize my parents to redeem the bonds on my behalf and transfer the equivalent value to me.

I know there are processes for giving authority to a third party (in this case, my parents) to redeem a bond on my behalf, but am unsure of which exactly it is and how time-consuming it is to do in this way.

Is the correct way to go about this to grant attorney-in-fact status to my parents?  Is it relatively simple to do or would it still be easier to have them mailed and go through redeeming/converting them myself?

Comment: Have them mail you the bonds, and then redeem them at your bank.  The money will go into your bank account, which you can then transfer to Schwab.

Comment: As described, there is no other bank account, otherwise I would not have asked this question.

Comment: It's ambiguous.  (And also why having an account at a bank with a local branch is useful: the internet is great, but sometimes speaking to a teller is darned useful.)

Comment: https://money.howstuffworks.com/personal-finance/budgeting/how-to-cash-in-savings-bonds2.htm "in some cases a person with the legal authority to conduct business on the bond bearer's behalf can redeem the bond. This is typically someone acting on behalf of a deceased person's estate."  A power of attorney might work.

Comment: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeredeem.htm